# Difference between functional dependency and join dependency

Tags: relational-theory

By definition, a **functional dependency** is defined as

> Let X and Y be subsets of attributes of a relation R. A functional dependency X → Y holds over R if and only if for any instance r of R,
>   whenever two tuples t1 and t2 of r agree on the attributes X, they
>   also agree on the attributes Y. That is,
>
> t1.X = t2.X ⇒ t1.Y = t2.Y

A **join dependency**, meanwhile,

> A table T is subject to a join dependency if T can always be recreated by joining multiple tables each having a subset of the attributes of T.

I could be wrong, but I was wondering if there are any relation between the concept of functional dependency and join dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join Dependencies can be considered a generalization of Multivalued Dependencies, following the fact that a Multivalued Dependency X →→ Y in a relation R can be seen as another way of writing a *binary* Join Dependency ⨝[XY, X(U − Y)], where U is the set of all the attributes of the relation R.

For instance, in a relation describing employees together with their salary history as well as other attributes `R(empNo, salary, year, name, role)`, we can say that there is a MultivaluedDependency `empNo →→ salary, year` or, equivalenty that there is a Join Dependency `⨝[{empNo, salary, year}, {empNo, name, role}]` (note that this makes clear that in R holds also the “dual” Multivalued Dependency `empNo →→ name, role`).

You are asking which relations there are between Functional Dependencies and Join Dependencies. The question is reasonable, since *there is* a relation between Functional Dependencies and Multivalued Dependencies.

In Chapter 8 of [Abiteboul, S. “Foundations of Databases.” Reading, Mass: Addison-Wesley, 1995.](http://webdam.inria.fr/Alice/) you can find an answer which is also proved:

> Proposition 8.3.3. Let U be a set of attributes, {X, Y, Z} be a partition of U, and Σ be a set of Functional Dependencies over U. Then Σ ⊨ ⨝[XY, XZ] if and only if either Σ ⊨ X → Y or Σ ⊨ X → Z.

In other words, if a Functional Dependency `X → Y` holds in a relation schema R, then this implies that the binary Join Dependency `⨝[XY, XZ]` holds, and viceversa. Note that this is equivalent to say that you can perform always a lossless decomposition of a relation `R{X,Y,Z}` with a functional dependency `X → Y` in `R1{XY}`, `R2{XZ}`.

So, for instance, in the previous example, since `empNo → name`, the Join Dependency `⨝[{empNo, name}, {empNo, salary, year, role}]` holds and `{R1(empNo, name), R2(empNo, salary, year, role)}` is a lossless decomposition.

Answer (score -1):

For those who are reading on this topic, I thought the following elaboration might be helpful.

From C.J. Date's *SQL and Relational Theory-How to Write Accurate SQL Code*, it is mentioned in Appendix B that

> It’s also immediate that every FD is a JD, because (as Heath’s theorem tells us) if R satisfies a certain FD, then it can be nonloss decomposed into certain projections (in other words, it satisfies a certain JD).

Essentially, [Heath's theorem](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psznza/G53RDB07/heath8.pdf) states

> Heath's theorem. • A relation R(X,Y,Z) that satisfies a functional dependency X → Y can always be non-loss decomposed into its projections R1=πXY(R) and R2=πXZ(R)

Comment: This quote is taken from Appendix B of the 1st version of C.J. Date’s book (2009). In the 2nd edition (2012), the contents of this appendix have been removed. We must now refer to “Database Design & Relational Theory, Normal Forms & All That Jazz” (2012), where is written (page 114) “FDs aren’t JDs) [...] every FD implies a JD [...] the converse is false”...